# How to get api's for socrata and soda

Tags: socrata, soda

I'm looking for access to SOCRATA and SODA via API

I searched CDC site https://dev.socrata.com/support.html and got this below: 
"If you’ve got questions about how to access Socrata data programmatically, or even just a general questions about Socrata, you can post them to Stack Overflow using the soda or socrata tags and we’ll help you out!"

I expect instructions for successfully applying for SODA and SOCRATA APIs

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I went to the CDC site and searched for help on this; the above is what I got (link included), as in my original post. That's what I have tried so far. Essentially, I was directed to Stack Overflow, with the keys included.

Comment: To get started with the API, I'd recommend that you take a look at [Socrata's developer site](https://dev.socrata.com/) to become acquainted with the API. If you have a favorite tool, such as R, Python, JavaScript, etc. you can look at supported [SDK and libraries](https://dev.socrata.com/libraries/).

Comment: Thank you so much, Tom. Your response is the complete and perfect answer.